# Why do I get a Reference Error: 'next()' is not defined, even though next is defined in my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, python-3.x

I have a javascript function named next() and it's meant to process information. Also, I call the function from the HTML. However, my firefox console returns a ReferenceError: 'next' is not defined. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

I'm also taking suggestions about how to better write the code. I'll be happy to incorporate your ideas.

Also for clarification, I want the button to make an ajax call to the Django backend and change the text on the screen.

I have tried setting the form action to `javascript: next()`, but no avail also.

```html
<form>
  <input class='btn btn-primary ml-auto' onclick="next()" id="next_button" type="button" role='button' value='Next'>
</form>
```

```js
count = '{{ question.id }}';

function next() {
  count++;
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url "next_question" %}',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'question_id': count
    },
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementbyId('question').innerText = data.fields.question;
      console.log(count);
    }
    error: function() {
      $('#next_button').disabled = true;
      alert("Either that's the last question or an error occured!");
    }
  });
};

if (confirm('Are you ready to start the test?')) {
  timer(10);
} else {
  window.location = '{% url "Home" %}'
};
```

I expect the text to some text to change or at least not to get the error:

> ReferenceError: next() is not defined.

Comment: Your `count` is  a string (due to `count = '{{ question.id }}'`, so `count++` is not possible.

Comment: Your `next()` function needs to be in global scope due to your use of the `onclick` attribute - ensure you've not placed it in a document.ready handler, for example.

Comment: Also make sure there is nothing else called next in the page

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It works fine for me on Firefox, provided that it's a String like `'3'`

Comment: You missed a `,` after your success in ajax call

Comment: The problem is there's a missing comma after the `success` function, which causes a syntax error, which causes the issue.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG. That solved it!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, welcome.

I will show you a best solution with all the code, ok?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input class='btn btn-primary ml-auto' id="next_button" type="button" role='button' value='Next'>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#next_button').on('click', function(){
                console.log('Whatever you want');
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

That code works for me on Mozilla..

Best Regards.

Comment: Please see the comments to understand why this isn't the problem, and why it's irrelevant.

Comment: jQuery `bind` and `unbind` are deprecated

Comment: That's true... sorry... I edited just to show just an improvement of the code.